no oled attached to /dev/i2c-0 - SDD1306
I am a newbie working on Raspberry Pi Pico W, I have built the linux image for PICO W and now interfacing 0.96 I2C OLED Display of SDD1306 with RPi Pico W. when I am building Linux image, I am getting errors while running the command ./ssd1306._bin _I 128x64 the error is “no oled attached to /dev/i2c-0”.
Can someone help me in solving this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
